# Handling for loop in angular js

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat, key-value

I have a below JSON response, I need to populate my role information based on the role selected, I just moved roleinformation in roleInfo array , but the problem is I am unable to populate the key and value in the table accordingly.I am able to get the value , but couldnt populate in table. I couldn't move the key and its value to the table . I need  move QA and Development with its sub key white box testing and Black box testing in my table. My for loop throw at error at end of termination.

JSON:

```
    {
      "json": {
        "response": {
          "servicetype": "1",
          "functiontype": "10011",
          "statuscode": "0",
          "statusmessage": "Success",
          "data": {
            "unassignedroles": [
              {"rolename":"1",
                "roleinformation": {
                  "QA": [
                    {
                      "White Box Testing": 0
                    },
                    {
                     "Black Box Testing": 10
                    }

                  ],
                       "Development": [
                    {
                      "White Box Testing": 0
                    },
                    {
                     "Black Box Testing": 10
                    }

                  ]
                }
              },
              {
`              "rolename":"2"`,
                "roleinformation": {
                  "1": [
                    {
                      "A": 0
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
```

JS:

```
       var roleInfo = [];
        UserService.getAssignRoles(json).then(function(response) {

 if (response.json.response.statuscode == 0 && response.json.response.statusmessage == 'Success')
{
    $scope.model.assignroles = [], assignrolesArray = [];

    var unasresdata = response.json.response.data.unassignedroles;
    var assresdata = response.json.response.data.assignedtoles;

    assignrolesArray = unasresdata.concat(assresdata);

    $scope.model.assignroles = assignrolesArray;
       for( var i = 0; i < assignrolesArray.length ; i++){

       if (($scope.model.rolename === assignrolesArray[i].rolename) && (assignrolesArray[i].rolename !== undefined )){
           roleInfo = assignrolesArray[i].roleinformation;
           for (i in roleInfo)

  }      
    }

    }
   });
```

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" name="role"
      ng-model="model.rolename"
      ng-change="getAssignRole(data,model.rolename)">
         <option selected>Select Roles</option>
         <option ng-repeat="role in model.assignroles track by $index"
        value="{{role.rolename}}">{{role.rolename}}</option>
 </select>    
 <div>        
      <table class="smalltable">
           <thead>
               <tr ng-repeat="i(key, value) in roleInfo">
                   <td>{{ key }}</td>
                   <td ng-repeat="details in value">
     `                 <p ng-repeat"(subkey, subvalue) in details">{{ subkey }} : {{ subvalue }}</p>
                   </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
       </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: can you add plunker for it?

Comment: Hi , I get this response via REST API. I am afraid I can not plunker it .

Comment: Your JS code seams to be incomplete. your inner for-clause `for (i in roleInfo)` doesn't have any content...

Comment: assignrolesArray[i].roleinformation is an object , but assigning it to roleinfo and using it as an array does not seem correct.

Comment: Hi for(i in roleInfo) will give value of i as Q and Development. But it replace them as loop runs. Thats what my question is , how to seperate the key and Value.

Comment: @ S kumar , So how I can use it. I am completely new to JS.

Comment: Create a plunkr and instead of calling the service, just put the hard coded data. This will help us help u better.

Comment: how we do dynamically , Because QA or Development is not going to be constant in roleinformation.

Answer (score 0):

Used angular.extend() to concate the object for roleInfo

```
$scope.roleInfo={};

 for( var i = 0; i < assignrolesArray.length ; i++){
           $scope.roleInfo = angular.extend($scope.roleInfo,assignrolesArray[i].roleinformation);         

  }
```

Refer to the below code and [plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/SWTqAHKAYnxYsHI5wxxq?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div>       
      <table>
           <thead>
               <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in roleInfo">
                   <td>{{ key }}</td>
                   <td ng-repeat="details in value">
                        <p ng-repeat="(subkey, subvalue) in details">
                           {{subkey}}:{{subvalue}}
                        </p>
                   </td>


                </tr>
            </thead>
       </table>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

var response =
{
    "json": {
        "response": {
            "servicetype": "1",
            "functiontype": "10011",
            "statuscode": "0",
            "statusmessage": "Success",
            "data": {
                "unassignedroles": [{
                    "rolename": "1",
                    "roleinformation": {
                        "QA": [{
                                "White Box Testing": 0
                            }, {
                                "Black Box Testing": 10
                            }

                        ],
                        "Development": [{
                                "White Box Testing": 0
                            }, {
                                "Black Box Testing": 10
                            }

                        ]
                    }
                }, {
                    "rolename": "2",
                    "roleinformation": {
                        "1": [{
                            "A": 0
                        }]
                    }
                }]

            }
        }
    }
};

 var unasresdata = response.json.response.data.unassignedroles;
 var assresdata = [{
                    "rolename": "1a",
                    "roleinformation": {
                        "QA": [{
                                "White Box Testing": 0
                            }, {
                                "Black Box Testing": 10
                            }

                        ],
                        "Development": [{
                                "White Box Testing": 0
                            }, {
                                "Black Box Testing": 10
                            }

                        ]
                    }
                }, {
                    "rolename": "2a",
                    "roleinformation": {
                        "1": [{
                            "A": 0
                        }]
                    }
                }];

    var assignrolesArray  = unasresdata.concat(assresdata);

     console.log("This is assignedrolesArray : "+ assignrolesArray);
     $scope.roleInfo={};

 for( var i = 0; i < assignrolesArray.length ; i++){
           $scope.roleInfo = angular.extend($scope.roleInfo,assignrolesArray[i].roleinformation);         

  }



});
</script>



</body>
</html>
```